# How can I use the compile time constant __LINE__ in a string [PHP]

Tags: php, constants

I have a PHP class file, I need to use the **`__ CLASS __`** , **`__ LINE __`** constants in lots of place. I don't want to write these tow constants in every place so, I have create the method called **`log_suffix()`** in my class file and using that method.

```
function detail(){
    $leave_groups = LeaveGroup::get_leave_group_details($this->company_id, 1, true); 

    if($this->debug){
        print_r($leave_groups->toArray());
    }

    if($leave_groups->count() === 0){
        Log::error("log: " . $this->log_suffix() );// Line 39
        return false;
    }

    return $leave_groups;
} 

function log_suffix(){
    return "$this->company_code | $this->company_name \t on File: ". _CLASS_. "\t". __LINE__ ; // Line no 51
}
```

the problem is, It is printing the line no **51** ( line constant written line ).

Is it possible to get the compile time line no that is **39** according to the shared image.

I know that with a try catch exception we can do this ( get the file and line no ).
rather than that is there any other way to sort out this issue.

[here is online editor link](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/h3k)

Comment: Don't post images of code. You need to copy/paste any code/errors into the question as text. Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Take `debug_backtrace()` and remove the first entry

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i want to elaborate the line number also in this post, that why I have posted a image

Comment: @LarsStegelitz the purpose is get the line number and write it to a log file. **debug_backtrace()** is not suitable for this scenario.

Comment: your code is wrong anyway, `log_suffix` is not declared static and you call it statically...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz now I have add a jdoodle link and fixed that issue

Comment: @NasikAhd You need to elaborate on what makes `debug_backtrace()` unsuitable for you. We can't suggest an alternative if we don't know what's wrong with this one.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález if want to say simply, I need the line number only to write to the log file. if I use **debug_backtrace** it will give more data like if i call 3 functions all three functions trace will be there

Comment: _"i want to elaborate the line number"_ - You can still write the line number even if you post the code as text, or add the image as an extra clarification. If you read that link, you'll see why it's important that you always post the code as text as well.

Comment: @NasikAhd: Then only use the information you need (from `debug_backtrace`)... have you checked what this function returns to the caller?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes and I have sort out the issue with accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [magic constants documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php), `__LINE__` contains the "The current line number of the file.", that is the line where it is used. Therefore, looking at the example posted, in the `log_suffix()` function it will always print **51**, wherever this function is called.
You could pass `__LINE__` as a parameter of this function when it is called, , because it will hold the line number where the function is actually called, but this is what you want to avoid.

Another possibility is to use [`debug_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function in `log_suffix()`, with parameter limit = 1. It will return an array with one key, whose value is an array. The 'line' key holds the line of the previous calling scope.

A quick example:

```
$debugTrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, 1);
$callerLine = $debugTrace[0]['line'];
```

Comment: **debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, 1)** solved the problem but, Actually I'm trying to do a cron job and above mentioned class file going to be in a loop may be in the production it can be process 100 times. so using **debug_backtrace** will create any performance problem?

Comment: Any line of code has impact on performance: it consumes CPU cycles...

Comment: Any call to a function has some overhead. If you are concerned by performance, you could do some measure testing with a high or reasonable or expected number of executions while in development ambient. You can measure the number of executions in a time frame or the time all the executions take, with or without the use of this function. This will not tell you how it will perform in production ambient, because conditions are different, but you have an idea of the impact overall compared to pass `__LINE__` as a parameter function.